# Converting Keras model to multi label output

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a model which takes in a dataframe which looks like this

```
image,level
10_left,0
10_right,0
13_left,0
```

with model structure like this

```
base_image_dir = 'extra_data/dr/'
retina_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_image_dir, 'trainLabels.csv'))
retina_df['PatientId'] = retina_df['image'].map(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
retina_df['path'] = retina_df['image'].map(lambda x: os.path.join(base_image_dir,'train',
                                                         '{}.jpeg'.format(x)))
retina_df['exists'] = retina_df['path'].map(os.path.exists)
print(retina_df['exists'].sum(), 'images found of', retina_df.shape[0], 'total')
retina_df['eye'] = retina_df['image'].map(lambda x: 1 if x.split('_')[-1]=='left' else 0)
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
retina_df['level_cat'] = retina_df['level'].map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, 1+retina_df['level'].max()))

retina_df.dropna(inplace = True)
retina_df = retina_df[retina_df['exists']]
retina_df.sample(3)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
rr_df = retina_df[['PatientId', 'level']].drop_duplicates()
train_ids, valid_ids = train_test_split(rr_df['PatientId'], 
                                   test_size = 0.25, 
                                   random_state = 2018,
                                   stratify = rr_df['level'])
raw_train_df = retina_df[retina_df['PatientId'].isin(train_ids)]
valid_df = retina_df[retina_df['PatientId'].isin(valid_ids)]
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
print('train', raw_train_df.shape[0], 'validation', valid_df.shape[0])

train_df = raw_train_df.groupby(['level', 'eye']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(75, replace = True)                                                    ).reset_index(drop = True)
print('New Data Size:', train_df.shape[0], 'Old Size:', raw_train_df.shape[0])

import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
IMG_SIZE = (512, 512) # slightly smaller than vgg16 normally expects
def tf_image_loader(out_size, 
                      horizontal_flip = True, 
                      vertical_flip = False, 
                     random_brightness = True,
                     random_contrast = True,
                    random_saturation = True,
                    random_hue = True,
                      color_mode = 'rgb',
                       preproc_func = preprocess_input,
                       on_batch = False):
    def _func(X):
        with tf.name_scope('image_augmentation'):
            with tf.name_scope('input'):
                X = tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(X), channels = 3 if color_mode == 'rgb' else 0)
                X = tf.image.resize_images(X, out_size)
            with tf.name_scope('augmentation'):
                if horizontal_flip:
                    X = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(X)
                if vertical_flip:
                    X = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(X)
                if random_brightness:
                    X = tf.image.random_brightness(X, max_delta = 0.1)
                if random_saturation:
                    X = tf.image.random_saturation(X, lower = 0.75, upper = 1.5)
                if random_hue:
                    X = tf.image.random_hue(X, max_delta = 0.15)
                if random_contrast:
                    X = tf.image.random_contrast(X, lower = 0.75, upper = 1.5)
                return preproc_func(X)
    if on_batch: 
        # we are meant to use it on a batch
        def _batch_func(X, y):
            return tf.map_fn(_func, X), y
        return _batch_func
    else:
        # we apply it to everything
        def _all_func(X, y):
            return _func(X), y         
        return _all_func

def tf_augmentor(out_size,
                intermediate_size = (640, 640),
                 intermediate_trans = 'crop',
                 batch_size = 16,
                   horizontal_flip = True, 
                  vertical_flip = False, 
                 random_brightness = True,
                 random_contrast = True,
                 random_saturation = True,
                    random_hue = True,
                  color_mode = 'rgb',
                   preproc_func = preprocess_input,
                   min_crop_percent = 0.001,
                   max_crop_percent = 0.005,
                   crop_probability = 0.5,
                   rotation_range = 10):

    load_ops = tf_image_loader(out_size = intermediate_size, 
                               horizontal_flip=horizontal_flip, 
                               vertical_flip=vertical_flip, 
                               random_brightness = random_brightness,
                               random_contrast = random_contrast,
                               random_saturation = random_saturation,
                               random_hue = random_hue,
                               color_mode = color_mode,
                               preproc_func = preproc_func,
                               on_batch=False)
    def batch_ops(X, y):
        batch_size = tf.shape(X)[0]
        with tf.name_scope('transformation'):
            # code borrowed from https://becominghuman.ai/data-augmentation-on-gpu-in-tensorflow-13d14ecf2b19
            # The list of affine transformations that our image will go under.
            # Every element is Nx8 tensor, where N is a batch size.
            transforms = []
            identity = tf.constant([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=tf.float32)
            if rotation_range > 0:
                angle_rad = rotation_range / 180 * np.pi
                angles = tf.random_uniform([batch_size], -angle_rad, angle_rad)
                transforms += [tf.contrib.image.angles_to_projective_transforms(angles, intermediate_size[0], intermediate_size[1])]

            if crop_probability > 0:
                crop_pct = tf.random_uniform([batch_size], min_crop_percent, max_crop_percent)
                left = tf.random_uniform([batch_size], 0, intermediate_size[0] * (1.0 - crop_pct))
                top = tf.random_uniform([batch_size], 0, intermediate_size[1] * (1.0 - crop_pct))
                crop_transform = tf.stack([
                      crop_pct,
                      tf.zeros([batch_size]), top,
                      tf.zeros([batch_size]), crop_pct, left,
                      tf.zeros([batch_size]),
                      tf.zeros([batch_size])
                  ], 1)
                coin = tf.less(tf.random_uniform([batch_size], 0, 1.0), crop_probability)
                transforms += [tf.where(coin, crop_transform, tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(identity, 0), [batch_size, 1]))]
            if len(transforms)>0:
                X = tf.contrib.image.transform(X,
                      tf.contrib.image.compose_transforms(*transforms),
                      interpolation='BILINEAR') # or 'NEAREST'
            if intermediate_trans=='scale':
                X = tf.image.resize_images(X, out_size)
            elif intermediate_trans=='crop':
                X = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(X, out_size[0], out_size[1])
            else:
                raise ValueError('Invalid Operation {}'.format(intermediate_trans))
            return X, y
    def _create_pipeline(in_ds):
        batch_ds = in_ds.map(load_ops, num_parallel_calls=4).batch(batch_size)
        return batch_ds.map(batch_ops)
    return _create_pipeline

def flow_from_dataframe(idg, 
                        in_df, 
                        path_col,
                        y_col, 
                        shuffle = True, 
                        color_mode = 'rgb'):
    files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((in_df[path_col].values, 
                                                   np.stack(in_df[y_col].values,0)))
    in_len = in_df[path_col].values.shape[0]
    while True:
        if shuffle:
            files_ds = files_ds.shuffle(in_len) # shuffle the whole dataset

        next_batch = idg(files_ds).repeat().make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        for i in range(max(in_len//32,1)):
            # NOTE: if we loop here it is 'thread-safe-ish' if we loop on the outside it is completely unsafe
            yield K.get_session().run(next_batch)

batch_size = 48
core_idg = tf_augmentor(out_size = IMG_SIZE, 
                        color_mode = 'rgb', 
                        vertical_flip = True,
                        crop_probability=0.0, # crop doesn't work yet
                        batch_size = batch_size) 
valid_idg = tf_augmentor(out_size = IMG_SIZE, color_mode = 'rgb', 
                         crop_probability=0.0, 
                         horizontal_flip = False, 
                         vertical_flip = False, 
                         random_brightness = False,
                         random_contrast = False,
                         random_saturation = False,
                         random_hue = False,
                         rotation_range = 0,
                        batch_size = batch_size)

train_gen = flow_from_dataframe(core_idg, train_df, 
                             path_col = 'path',
                            y_col = 'level_cat')

valid_gen = flow_from_dataframe(valid_idg, valid_df, 
                             path_col = 'path',
                            y_col = 'level_cat') # we can use much larger batches for evaluation

t_x, t_y = next(valid_gen)
t_x, t_y = next(train_gen)
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16 as PTModel
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2 as PTModel
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3 as PTModel
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Input, Conv2D, multiply, LocallyConnected2D, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
in_lay = Input(t_x.shape[1:])
base_pretrained_model = PTModel(input_shape =  t_x.shape[1:], include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
base_pretrained_model.trainable = False
pt_depth = base_pretrained_model.get_output_shape_at(0)[-1]
pt_features = base_pretrained_model(in_lay)
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
bn_features = BatchNormalization()(pt_features)

attn_layer = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(Dropout(0.5)(bn_features))
attn_layer = Conv2D(16, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(attn_layer)
attn_layer = Conv2D(8, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(attn_layer)
attn_layer = Conv2D(1, 
                    kernel_size = (1,1), 
                    padding = 'valid', 
                    activation = 'sigmoid')(attn_layer)
# fan it out to all of the channels
up_c2_w = np.ones((1, 1, 1, pt_depth))
up_c2 = Conv2D(pt_depth, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', 
               activation = 'linear', use_bias = False, weights = [up_c2_w])
up_c2.trainable = False
attn_layer = up_c2(attn_layer)

mask_features = multiply([attn_layer, bn_features])
gap_features = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(mask_features)
gap_mask = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(attn_layer)
# to account for missing values from the attention model
gap = Lambda(lambda x: x[0]/x[1], name = 'RescaleGAP')([gap_features, gap_mask])
gap_dr = Dropout(0.25)(gap)
dr_steps = Dropout(0.25)(Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(gap_dr))
out_layer = Dense(t_y.shape[-1], activation = 'softmax')(dr_steps)
retina_model = Model(inputs = [in_lay], outputs = [out_layer])
from keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy
def top_2_accuracy(in_gt, in_pred):
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(in_gt, in_pred, k=2)

retina_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                           metrics = ['categorical_accuracy', top_2_accuracy])
retina_model.summary()
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
weight_path="{}_weights.best.hdf5".format('retina')

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(weight_path, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, 
                             save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_weights_only = True)

reduceLROnPlat = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.8, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.0001, cooldown=5, min_lr=0.0001)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", 
                      mode="min", 
                      patience=6) # probably needs to be more patient, but kaggle time is limited
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, early, reduceLROnPlat]

retina_model.fit_generator(train_gen, 
                           steps_per_epoch = train_df.shape[0]//batch_size,
                           validation_data = valid_gen, 
                           validation_steps = valid_df.shape[0]//batch_size,
                              epochs = 25, 
                              callbacks = callbacks_list,
                             workers = 0, # tf-generators are not thread-safe
                             use_multiprocessing=False, 
                             max_queue_size = 0
                            )
retina_model.load_weights(weight_path)
retina_model.save('full_retina_model.h5')
```

I realize that's a lot of code, but i what i want to do is take in a dataframe which look like this

```
image,N,D,G,C,A,H,M,O
2857_left,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3151_left,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3113_left,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

and in order to achive this i have made this following changes,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
rr_df = retina_df
y = rr_df[['N', 'D', 'G','C','A', 'H', 'M', 'O']]
train_ids, valid_ids = train_test_split(rr_df['PatientId'], 
                                   test_size = 0.25, 
                                   random_state = 2018)

raw_train_df = retina_df[retina_df['PatientId'].isin(train_ids)]
valid_df = retina_df[retina_df['PatientId'].isin(valid_ids)]
print('train', raw_train_df.shape[0], 'validation', valid_df.shape[0])
train_df = raw_train_df

from keras import regularizers, optimizers
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
in_lay = Input(t_x.shape[1:])
base_pretrained_model = PTModel(input_shape =  t_x.shape[1:], include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
base_pretrained_model.trainable = False
pt_depth = base_pretrained_model.get_output_shape_at(0)[-1]
pt_features = base_pretrained_model(in_lay)
bn_features = BatchNormalization()(pt_features)

# here we do an attention mechanism to turn pixels in the GAP on an off

attn_layer = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(Dropout(0.5)(bn_features))
attn_layer = Conv2D(16, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(attn_layer)
attn_layer = Conv2D(8, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(attn_layer)
attn_layer = Conv2D(1, 
                    kernel_size = (1,1), 
                    padding = 'valid', 
                    activation = 'sigmoid')(attn_layer)
# fan it out to all of the channels
up_c2_w = np.ones((1, 1, 1, pt_depth))
up_c2 = Conv2D(pt_depth, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', 
               activation = 'linear', use_bias = False, weights = [up_c2_w])
up_c2.trainable = False
attn_layer = up_c2(attn_layer)

mask_features = multiply([attn_layer, bn_features])
gap_features = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(mask_features)
gap_mask = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(attn_layer)
# to account for missing values from the attention model
gap = Lambda(lambda x: x[0]/x[1], name = 'RescaleGAP')([gap_features, gap_mask])
gap_dr = Dropout(0.25)(gap)
x = Dropout(0.25)(Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(gap_dr))
# out_layer = Dense(t_y.shape[-1], activation = 'softmax')(dr_steps)
output1 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output2 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output3 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output4 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output5 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output6 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output7 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output8 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
retina_model = Model(inputs = [in_lay], outputs = [output1,output2,output3,output4,output5, output6, output7, output8])
# retina_model = Model([in_lay],output1,output2,output3,output4,output5, output6, output7, output8)
# retina_model.build(t_x.shape[1:]) # `input_shape` is the shape of the input data

# print(model.summary())

# retina_model.compile(optimizers.rmsprop(lr = 0.00001, decay = 1e-6),
loss = ["binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy", "binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy"]#,metrics = ["accuracy"])

# retina_model = Model(inputs = [in_lay], outputs = [out_layer])
# from keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy
# def top_2_accuracy(in_gt, in_pred):
    # return top_k_categorical_accuracy(in_gt, in_pred, k=2)

retina_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = loss,
                           metrics = ['accuracy'])
retina_model.summary()
```

but when i run this i get,

```
 ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 8 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   ...
```

Any suggestions on how i could change this model to train this on multi label inputs.Thanks in advance.

Comment: nice try. I think you should ask the original author of this model (Kevin Mader) directly on kaggle. Hope he can give more insight n direction. [kevin_mader-src](https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/attention-on-pretrained-vgg16-for-bone-age)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to train a model with 8 different outputs (length 1 for every output)  but your target values is an array of length 8.

The easiest fix is to replace:

```
output1 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output2 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output3 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output4 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output5 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output6 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output7 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output8 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)

loss = ["binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy", "binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy"]#,metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

with:

```
#leave sigmoid here, don't change with softmax if it is a multilabel problem
output = Dense(8, activation = 'sigmoid')(x) 
loss = "binary_crossentropy"
```

otherwise you have to create a custom generator with yielding a list of 8 targets  to feed your network